# Mongoose aggregation $lookup how to change "from" field depending on a condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, lookup, aggregation

i want to join with a different table depending on a variable in the document
note im using mongoose

```
$lookup: {
  from: { 
    if: { $eq: [ "$ownerType", 2 ] }, 
    then: 'hi', 
    else: 'hello' 
  },
  localField: "ownerID",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "members"
}
```

Comment: Needs details or clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, The `from` field can't be a variable.

There's an open ticket for this feature that you can follow [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497) however it's been open for more than 4 years so clearly it's not top priority.

What I recommend you do is use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for each of the conditions like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            cond1: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {$ne: ["$ownerType", 2]}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "hello",
                        localField: "ownerID",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "members"
                    }
                }
            ],
            cond2: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {$eq: ["$ownerType", 2]}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "hi",
                        localField: "ownerID",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "members"
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    }
]);
```

The `$match` conditions make this query be efficiency close to a single `$lookup` and you can just merge the results after the `$facet` stage into one array.

Comment: Mongodb wont use index keys inside $facet stage. It would be fast if we write 2 separate queries